# How to remove many rows duplicate in two datatable?

Tags: c#

I using C#. I have 2 datatable `dtUser, dtUserNotAllow`.

I want to check all rows in `dtUser`is contain in datatable `dtUserNotAllow`? If it have, remove it.

Like this.

`dtUser: user1  user2 user8`

`dtUserNotAllow: user2`.

This will delete user2.

=> `dtUser: user1 user8`

```
foreach(DataRow rows in dtUserNotAllow)
{
    if(dtUser.Columns.Contains(rows["user_name"].ToString()))
    {

    }
}
```

But show error like:

`foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Data.DataTable' because 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Comment: @Ian did my answer help you solving your problem?

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace

```
foreach(DataRow rows in dtUserNotAllow)
```

with

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtUserNotAllow.Rows)
```

to remove invalid rows, your code should look something like

```
List<String> lUserNotAllow = dtUserNotAllow.AsEnumerable().Select(x => (string)x["user_name"]).ToList();
foreach (DataRow row in dtUser.Rows)
{
    if(dtUserNotAllow.AsEnumerable().Any(x => row["user_name"]  == x["user_name"]))   
    {
        dtUser.Rows.Remove(row);
    }
}
```

to iterate through the rows of the `DataTable`